# How Can I Delete Temporary Internet Files/Content.IE5/Index.dat?

Tags: windows-vista, temporary-files, index.dat

Without purchasing someone elses software, how can I as a software engineer, delete index.dat?  What OS Voodoo hoops do I have to jump through to accomplish the simple deletion of a single file on my own computer?  I have windows Vista.

Comment: @ Joshua ask this qusetion in superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

System files are normally locked by `explorer.exe`. Since this is Stackoverflow you'll get a solution in the form of a program:

Enter the following code into a new file `purge.bat`:

```
taskkill explorer.exe
del %1%
%system%\explorer.exe
```

From the command prompt (`cmd.exe`), execute as follows:

```
> purge "yourpath\Index.dat"
```

and presto, your file is gone.

The same thing can of course be done using the task manager (to kill and then run `explorer.exe`), but where's the fun in that?

Answer (score 0):

You can login as admin and delete index.dat. If  you are currently admin, just create a second admin account, log on and delete anything you want. Or you can delete it using a startup script which runs before the users logs-on and acquires a lock on index.dat. Or you can use Unlocker, a free software which can forcefully unlock any file in your account while you are being logged on.